# Phalcon\Session\Bag.. how to use them?

Tags: php, phalcon

In my project i use following code to access session variables via Session Bags in services:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Create session bag
    $className = get_class($this);
    $this->storage = new Phalcon\Session\Bag($className);    
}
```

But this gives an exception "A dependency injection object is required to access the 'session' service".

Ok, it seems that we need to setup a DI here. Most simple way - to define not shared sessionBag service in DI ($di will be set automatically then). But how can i understand which name i should setup for Session bag this way? Example:

```
$di->set('sessionBag', function() use ($config) {
    $name = ''; // ???
    $bag = new \Phalcon\Session\Bag($name);
    return $bag;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your class inherit from Phalcon\DI\Injectable, a session bag is implicitly created when you access the persistent property:

```
class MyComponent extends Phalcon\DI\Injectable
{

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $this->persistent->someName = "peter";
    }

}
```

Comment: This helped me realize that $this->persistent basically removes the need to explicitly call $this->session->start() before using Phalcon\Session\Bag

Answer (score 0):

```
//Start the session the first time when some component request
// the session service
$di->setShared('session', function() {
    $session = new Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files();
    $session->start();
    return $session;
});
```

Example:

auth.php:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->_di = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault ();
    $this->user       = new \Phalcon\Session\Bag(get_class());
    $this->user->setDI($this->_di);
}

/**
 *
 * @param int
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authenticate($identity){
    $this->user->identity=$identity;
}
/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isAuthenticate(){
    return $this->user->identity?true:false;
}
```